# ClassCastException ListView Footer

Tags: android-listview

I am trying to set a footerview on an android listview.  The listview uses a custom adapter in  which I show two types of rows both of which comply to a java interface.  The code to set the footer is as shown below:

```
    eventsList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.events_list);

    // create view for footer
    LL = new LinearLayout(getSherlockActivity());
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LayoutParams LLParams = new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LL.setLayoutParams(LLParams);

    eventsList.addFooterView(LL, null, false);

    // set up the array list for list rows and headers
    items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();

    loadEventsData();

    eventsAdapter = new TwoTypeArrayAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), items);

    eventsList.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
```

I keep getting a "java.lang.ClassCastException:  android.app.ActionBar&LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams".  The error is thrown at the line:

```
 eventsList.setAdapter(eventsAdapter);
```

The arrayAdapter is defined as follows:

```
 public class TwoTypeArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

   LayoutInflater mInflater;

   public enum RowType {
    LIST_ITEM,
    HEADER_ITEM
   }

   public TwoTypeArrayAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   }

   @Override
   public int getViewTypeCount() {
       return RowType.values().length;
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemViewType(int position) {
       return getItem(position).getViewType();
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       return getItem(position).getView(mInflater, convertView);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: can you show the definition of TwoTypeArrayAdapter

Comment: Thanks.  I've added the Adapter definition above.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple.  I just created the linear layout, LL in an xml file and then matched it's layout parameters to its parents with:

LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));